# How to restore function using PG_RESTORE

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I did the backup of my database:

```
-bash-4.2$ pg_dump -d mydb --format=custom -f /tmp/dump 
-bash-4.2$
```

Below checked and I saw my functions there:

```
-bash-4.2$ pg_restore -l /tmp/dump | grep -i addconf
233; 1255 39949 FUNCTION public addconfiguration(text) mydb
247; 1255 39950 FUNCTION public addconfiguration2(text) mydb
273; 1255 39951 FUNCTION public addconfiguration3(text) mydb
```

Then I tried to restore one function using the Postgres [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) instructions:

```
-bash-4.2$ pg_restore -d postgres --function=addconfiguration2(text) -v /tmp/dump 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I also tried without the parentheses and the arg, but it didn't work:

```
-bash-4.2$ pg_restore -d postgres --function=addconfiguration2 -v /tmp/dump 
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: implied data-only restore
```

After the attempts I verified if the function was created using `\df` inside psql, but without success.

**How could I restore functions using pg_restore?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parenthesis is special to the shell.  You don't have to remove it, you have to quote/escape it to get it to pass through the shell.

```
pg_restore -d postgres --function='addconfiguration2(text)' -v /tmp/dump
```